# Correct way to write an ASP.NET MVC action returning a PartialViewResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written an Action method for an ASP.NET MVC controller, which is being used to provide a model to a usercontrol.

public class ProductsController : Controller
    {

```
    public PartialViewResult ProductSummary()
    {
        ViewData.Model = new ProductSummaryModel("42"); // dummy data for now

        return new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewData = ViewData
        };
    }
}
```

I am using the 'futures' `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` dll and rendering the control in my main view like this :

```
<% Html.RenderAction<ProductsController>(x => x.ProductSummary()); %>
```

What I have here appears to work just fine, but i attempted to google [`new PartialResult()`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22new+PartialViewResult%22) to see if what I was doing was following the correct patterns.

Currently this search only comes up with 4 results!

So I figured I'm doing somethin wrong here in my controller. Whats the correct way to create an action method that returns a partial view? And what (if anything) is wrong or bad about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually just use:

```
return PartialView("MyView", myModel);
```

But this just returns a new PartialViewResult("MyView", myModel) so it is potatoes/potatoes.

Comment: what i had just looked bad. especially ViewData = ViewData. it felt wrong